# Exracting Interleaved floating point data

Tags: c, cuda, casting

For anybody using the cufft library from cuda (or somebody that knows their stuff)- what is the most efficient way to recover data from the interleaved data type cufftComplex?

Data is added to the structure as follows:

```
cufftComplex SomeData;
/*...a loop...*/ 
SomeData[i].x=1.0f;
SomeData[i].y=0.0f;
```

So now if I cast `&(SomeData[0].x&` as a pointer to a float, I have data in the form "1 0 1 0 1 " Because the x/y data is interleaved. I want to correctly type it so that I get "1 1 1 1 " ect. Is there a way to recast this type without using a loop and directly assigning the elements?

Thanks for any info. As I previously mentioned this is part of the CUDA sdk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it just by casting - the underlying data is interleaved and there is no way around that. If you really do need a contiguous stream of e.g. real-only data then you will have to de-interleave the data, which you can do either in place or out-of-place.